# How to map textures in openGL

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, graphics

How to map textures in openGL.Specifically i am having one cube and i want to paste a texture.
That texture much be transparent and "SOURCE" written on it.
Is it possible. If you want i can give the code of cube also. Please let me know.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried looking up how to do this at all, or tried doing it at all? If you check for Texture Mapping on Google there are several fully featured resources on this.

Answer (score 3):

Please check [lesson 06 from NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on those lessons: http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=02